# Не выполняется Тест в VS 2010

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

> Test run 'User@USER-2E89D2D1B2 2016-05-16 09:55:57' could not be
>   executed. No agents are marked online to execute test run.
>   USER-2E89D2D1B2

Comment: При запуске тестов в солюшне в Tes Result возникает сообщение Not executed.

Comment: Настройки выполнения тестов локальные.

Comment: У класса есть атрибут [TestClass]? У метода есть атрибут [TestMethod]?  Приведите пример кода, экстрасенсов здесь нет

Answer (score 1):

Все атрибуты имеются был сделан апдейт из svn. Target framework изменен с 4 на 3.5. Проблема решена